# setTimer does not work with Jquery hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, settimeout

I am trying to make simple effects to the menu with Jquery hover.
Here is my Javascript:

```
$(".goodi").hover(function () {    // make width 50px on mousenter
     elemin = this;
     $(elemin).animate({
         "height": "50px"
     }, 1000);
 }, function () {
     elemout = this;
     setTimeout(function () {  //  restore width to 100px in 1 second after mouseleave
         $(elemout).animate({
             "height": "100px"
         }, 1000);
     }, 1000);
 });
```

And here is html and CSS just for demo:

```
.goodi {
background:lightgrey;
width: 100px;
height:100px;
float:left;
margin:10px;    }

<div class="goodi"></div>
<div class="goodi"></div>
<div class="goodi"></div>
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zergius2/fnkcrups/9/).

The problem I have and spent whole day trying to fix it:  **when I hover fast enough on all of .goodi divs,  they change their height,  but only the last one hovered restores it back to 100px.**  setTimeout must work for each div hovered,  but it doesnt.

Any ideas?   Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also if user is very happy you don't want the OUT animation to be triggered everytime

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gnbdkebt/4/)

```
$(".goodi").each(function () {
var timer;
$(this).hover(function () {
   clearTimeout(timer);
   var  elemin = this;
     $(elemin).stop().animate({
         "height": "50px"
     }, 1000);
 }, function () {
    var elemout = this;
     clearTimeout(timer);
     timer = setTimeout(function () {
         $(elemout).stop().animate({
             "height": "100px"
         }, 1000);
     }, 1000);
 })
});
```

Comment: Boris, edit in the `.stop()`s from my answer, then this is the best answer.

Comment: You need a few little fixes too. (1) `var timer;` will suffice. (2) `clearTimeout(timer)` is safe without the test. (3) `clearTimeout(timer)` also needs to be performed in the mousleave handler, before setting the new timeout. Overwriting `timer` won't cancel a timeout that's already pending.

Comment: @Roamer-1888, Thank you for the additional edits. I'm used to write paranoid code that is why I wrote the default value(1) and the check(2). For (3) I prefer the `clearTimeout` to be at the beginning. Because if user goes mad over the elements, it will prevent exit animation on new enter of the mouse(if the new entry animation occurs before the old exit animation)

Comment: Boris, for the most part you can get away without `clearTimeout` in the mouseleave handler because a mouseeneter will precede a mouseout. But what if `mouseleave` was triggered from javascript? I have made the mistake of not doing a `clearTimeout`in very similar code, then taking ages to spot my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

you need to define the variables `elemin` and `elemout` locally

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gnbdkebt/)**

```
 $(".goodi").hover(function () {
   var  elemin = this;
     $(elemin).animate({
         "height": "50px"
     }, 1000);
 }, function () {
    var elemout = this;
     setTimeout(function () {
         $(elemout).animate({
             "height": "100px"
         }, 1000);
     }, 1000);
 });
```